# Local Java package management system in Python PIP style?

Tags: java, scala, maven, groovy, kotlin

I want to program in Java or other JVM languages like Scala, Kotlin, or Groovy. When I am programming on my projects, I only want to have import statements in my Java/Scala/Kotlin source files without the need to state the packages a second time in a Gradle/Maven build script. Instead I want to work as I would do in Python, i.e. have my import statements at the beginning of my source files and I am done.

The packages should then automatically included when I am compiling if all packages are installed in a central local package management system or otherwise get an error message telling me that I have to install a missing package. It should essentially work the same as for Python and PIP respectively.

Is a workflow like this possible preferably with Groovy or Maven?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can think is [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html):

> Grape is a JAR dependency manager embedded into Groovy. Grape lets you quickly add maven repository dependencies to your classpath, making scripting even easier. The simplest use is as simple as adding an annotation to your script:

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring-orm', version='3.2.5.RELEASE')
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

Like in [this example](https://gist.github.com/lyhcode/4387321):

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.16')
def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
def page = new XmlParser(parser).parse('https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=zh-TW&tab=wn')
page.depthFirst().DIV.grep{ it.'@class'=='title' }.each {
  println it.A.SPAN.text()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't judge the Groovy landscape since I don't have any experience there, but for developing Java or Scala applications this exact workflow is not possible as far as I know.

Regarding "I only want to have import statements..." I think the closest you can get is good Maven/Gradle/sbt integration in an IDE, like IntelliJ that automatically adds the desired library to your build system's configuration file when using the correct shortcut. It (at least) works for some Java libraries when you're dealing with a Maven project in IntelliJ.

And regarding your other wish to have packages automatically included when compiling: On the JVM there is the concept of the fat JAR (also called uber JAR), which is basically a JAR (Java archive) that contains all dependencies and is thus self-contained. Usually you can start the application contained in it with a single `java` command.

To build fat JARs you need to have the approriate plugin for your build system:

- For Maven that would be the *maven shade plugin*, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
- For sbt you can use the *assembly plugin*, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly
- Gradle probably has something similar
- A lot of Java frameworks also come with their own build plugins that make building such self-contained applications relatively simple ([Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) is one example, but only suitable for applications that on top of an HTTP server)

Hope this helps, althought it's not an accurate answer to your question. :)